# How to publish Vue3 components each in separate NPM registry

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs3

I have blank Vue3 application created with `npm init vue@3` and I want to publish each of my future components in private NPM registry so I can install them like:

```
npm i @my-registry/app/component-name
```

I am new in NPM packages and want to know whether is it possible to do so.

Comment: Search for private npm registry and follow one of the many guides

Comment: I know how to build and publish private NPM package via Vite. I just wanted to know how to publish my packages like I described in my question - each component in separate NPM package